# Pass all 2nd dimensional array values by using the first dimension to another array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

The questions may be a lil confusing and i am very sorry about it

So.. let says that i have 2 2-dimensional array

```
int[,] first = new int[2,3];
int[,] second = new int[2,3] { { 1, 1, 1 }, { 4, 3, 1 } };
```

Now what i want to do is copy all of the second array to the first

Something like this maybe?

```
first[] = second[];
```

Is this even possible without using for and pass the value one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.Copy()` like this:

```
int[,] first = new int[2, 3];
int[,] second = new int[2, 3] { { 1, 1, 1 }, { 4, 3, 1 } };

Array.Copy(second, first, second.Length);
```

If you would use `first = second;`, it would pass the reference to it. so if you change a value on the second array it would also change the value on the first. So `Array.Copy()` is what you want.

Comment: Currently trying it out, but i'm still confused about one thing
What is the 3rd parameter (length) for? Is it the length of how many array elements i want to copy or... what?

Comment: @NathanaelAldo yes thats the length of how many elements you want to copy. But your IDE should already tell you that.

Comment: @NathanaelAldo if my answer was helpful, you should mark it as correct so others know it aswell.

Comment: Not that i didnt mark your answer, but my reputation is below 15 so public won't be able to see it
Either way, thanks @sLw